# How to remove XML nodes based on conditions using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

From the following XML file, I want to remove "ColumnBlocks" tag based on one condition. Condition is- If the value of the FixedFloat tag is Float, then I want to delete ColumnBlocks tag from XML. My XML is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FirstTag>
    <SecondTag>
        <CategoryGroups>
            <Group>
                <Category>
                    <PricingDetails>
                        <SimplePricingDetails>
                            <FixedFloat>Fixed</FixedFloat>
                        </SimplePricingDetails>
                    </PricingDetails>
                    <rowVolume>
                        <ColumnBlocks>
                            <ColumnBlock>
                                <Column>abcd</Column>                               
                            </ColumnBlock>
                            <ColumnBlock>
                                <Column>xyz</Column>                                
                            </ColumnBlock>
                        </ColumnBlocks>
                    </rowVolume>
                    <row>jsdf<row>
                </Category>
                <Category>
                    <PricingDetails>
                        <SimplePricingDetails>
                            <FixedFloat>Float</FixedFloat>
                        </SimplePricingDetails>
                    </PricingDetails>
                    <rowVolume>
                        <ColumnBlocks>
                            <ColumnBlock>
                                <Column>abcd</Column>                               
                            </ColumnBlock>
                            <ColumnBlock>
                                <Column>xyz</Column>                                
                            </ColumnBlock>
                        </ColumnBlocks>
                    </rowVolume>
                    <row>jsdf<row>
                </Category>
            </Group>
        </CategoryGroups>
    </SecondTag>
</FirstTag>
```

I want the final code to not have ColumnBlocks from the Category, where FixedFloat value is Float. It should look like the below XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FirstTag>
    <SecondTag>
        <CategoryGroups>
            <Group>
                <Category>
                    <PricingDetails>
                        <SimplePricingDetails>
                            <FixedFloat>Fixed</FixedFloat>
                        </SimplePricingDetails>
                    </PricingDetails>
                    <rowVolume>
                        <ColumnBlocks>
                            <ColumnBlock>
                                <Column>abcd</Column>                               
                            </ColumnBlock>
                            <ColumnBlock>
                                <Column>xyz</Column>                                
                            </ColumnBlock>
                        </ColumnBlocks>
                    </rowVolume>
                    <row>jsdf<row>
                </Category>
                <Category>
                    <PricingDetails>
                        <SimplePricingDetails>
                            <FixedFloat>Float</FixedFloat>
                        </SimplePricingDetails>
                    </PricingDetails>
                    <rowVolume>
                    </rowVolume>
                    <row>jsdf<row>
                </Category>
            </Group>
        </CategoryGroups>
    </SecondTag>
</FirstTag>
```

Comment: I do not understand why would you delete it. It is never good practice to delete something from generated xml file. You can simply check if that's `<FixedFloat>Float</FixedFloat>` and then ignore that node

Comment: I am sorry if I misunderstood but I want to delete from **original XML** not generated one. I want to remove that node from the final XML as I don't need that node if  ```<FixedFloat>``` is equal to Float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the identity transformation template as a starting point and then add an empty template for the elements you want to remove:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Category[PricingDetails/SimplePricingDetails/FixedFloat = 'Float']/rowVolume/ColumnBlocks"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFepx

Comment: Perfect, it worked! Thanks a lot. Since I am new to this, would you mind explaining how the above XSLT works?

Comment: @Kartik, if "use the identity transformation template as a starting point and then add an empty template for the elements you want to remove" doesn't sound like an explanation to you then I guess you need to start with a book, https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm is one serving as an introduction and is available online.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ColumnBlocks">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ancestor::Category/descendant::FixedFloat = 'Float'"> </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <text>NO Output</text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can also try smallest code which following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//ColumnBlocks[ancestor::Category/descendant::FixedFloat = 'Float']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```